# How do I Fix a bad character that appears when i zoom on highstock

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a Highstock chart which is showing bad characters on the x-axis when i zoom with mouse or when i click on the button 1m / 1d.

I am using  Highstock v2.0.1.

you can see exactly what happens on this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtBqD.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should set utf-8 encoding on site and html file.